# Using CMake with Qt + brew OSX

Tags: macos, qt, cmake, homebrew

I am using a homebrew installed version of Qt(4.8.5) with CMake. The detection process in producing a strange QT_INCLUDE_DIR value of

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.5/include/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.5/lib/QtCore.framework
```

This location does not exist and QT headers are not found by Xcode. Is this an issue with brew CMake recipes ? What would be a logical fix in the CMakeLists for the project.